# How do you access ant properties from within a shellscript task?

Tags: ant, shell

In ant you can do something like:

```
<property name="version" value="${some.fake.version}"

<shellscript shell="bash" dir="${build.dir}"> 
   echo "some shell cmds"
   df -h
   ls *
   svn export http://svn.org/somedir              
</shellscript>
```

Okay, that shell script doesn't do anything, I know, but how would I the property "version" from within that shellscript?

I know you can do all of the above in Java scripting which is better than most  uses, but in the real script I'm doing a ton of svn commands which I'll have to shell out for anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [shellscript documentation](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/shellscript.html):

> Embedded ant properties will be
>   converted.

So you can use the ${variable} notation:

```
<shellscript shell="bash" dir="${build.dir}"> 
   echo "Version: ${version}"
</shellscript>
```

Comment: That worked.  I tried that very same thing first, but I did it on another variable that had problems up the stack, so I wasn't seeing the value.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ["official" SVN Ant Tasks](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html) available if you didn't want to write your own.

Otherwise, since `ShellScript` extends [`Exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) you could use arguments.

```
<shellscript shell="bash" dir="${build.dir}"> 
  <arg value="${someproperty}"/>
   echo $1
</shellscript>
```